# DKIM signatures to Rails application using Amazon SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, amazon-ses, dkim

We're using the ActionMailer with SMTP as our delivery method and Amazon SES as our outgoing mail provider.

We want to sign the emails with DKIM.
How can we do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used [DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) via ActionMailer with [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) myself yet, but here's how I'd approach it:

- Review [Authenticating Email with DKIM](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/DKIM.html) and take note of the closing note specifically:

> **Note**
>
> If you are using the Amazon SES SMTP interface to send email, and
> your client software automatically performs DKIM signing, you should
> check to ensure that your client does not sign any of the headers
> listed above. We recommend that you check the documentation for your
> software to find out exactly what headers are signed with DKIM.

- Checkout John Hawthorn's [DKIM signing library](https://github.com/jhawthorn/dkim) (see his [Introducing the dkim gem](http://www.johnhawthorn.com/2011/07/introducing-dkim-gem/) as well); section *Usage With Rails*  shows how to *sign all ActionMailer deliveries*:

```ruby
# Configure dkim globally (see above)
Dkim::domain      = 'example.com'
Dkim::selector    = 'mail'
Dkim::private_key = open('private.pem').read

# UPDATE [John Hawthorn]: SES developer guide recommends against signing these
Dkim::signable_headers = Dkim::DefaultHeaders - \
    %w{Message-ID Resent-Message-ID Date Return-Path Bounces-To}

# This will sign all ActionMailer deliveries
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor('Dkim::Interceptor')
```

#### Update

John Hawthorn has updated the code fragment with the required SES exceptions (see respectively commented line above), confirming that his apparently excellent dkim gem is indeed
<strike>If the mentioned SES/DKIM header exception requirements can be met by the dkim gem,this looks like</strike> a remarkable easy way to achieve your goal - thanks John!

Comment: I am also using the dkim gem with a similar configuration to the above. Works great together with the aws-ses gem for sending email via the SES API.

Comment: How did you create private.pem file?

Comment: @xuraj - Generating a proper DKIM private key is outside the scope of this question. That said, if you really wanna do it, start from [Manual DKIM Signing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/DKIM.Manual.html); however, as mentioned there as well, nowadays I'd highly recommend to look into the Amazon SES [Easy DKIM](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/DKIM.EasyDKIM.html) feature first, which allows you to skip manual DKIM handling all together in favor of automatic handling by SES.

Comment: @SteffenOpel Thanks for your response. I did sign using the easy DKIM feature but the emails in hotmail goto junk folder. Gmail and Yahoo addresses reach in inbox though. I am using ActionMailer to send email. Any suggestions for the junk mail problem? If I use the easy DKIM feature, do I still have to use the DKIM gem?

Comment: @xuraj - You don't need to (and shouldn't) use the DKIM gem in addition to Easy DKIM: you can verify the latter working correctly by inspecting the source of your emails, which contain a `DKIM-Signature:` header field  in case. Already existing junk folder issues aren't necessarily resolved the minute you start using authentication mechanisms, rather building reputation with ISPs can take a while and email reputation is a complex issue in general - check the SES [Whitepaper on Email Best Practices](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx2GBEOGDU758MG/New-Whitepaper-on-Email-Best-Practices) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dkim project to do that for you :

https://github.com/jhawthorn/dkim

Answer (score 0):

You can take it completely out of your source code and let SES do the DKIM signing for you.  Works great.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/simple-email-service-easy-domainkeys-identified-mail-support/